# Split string into multiple arrays fast

Tags: ruby

I have 100,000 strings of length 10, which needs to be split in 9 ways as shown below

```
10 # the whole string
5 x 5 # 2 strings of length 5 each
4 x 6 # and so on...
6 x 4
3 x 3 x 4
3 x 4 x 3
4 x 3 x 3
3 x 7
7 x 3
```

So for example the string `WGWJAWMPPJ` would turn into

```
WGWJAWMPPJ
WGWJA WMPPJ
WGWJ AWMPPJ
WGWJAW MPPJ
WGW JAW MPPJ
WGW JAWM PPJ
WGWJ AWM PPJ
WGW JAWMPPJ
WGWJAWM PPJ
```

The code I wrote is below

```
def breakdown(str)
  [
    [str],
    [str[0..4], str[5..9]],
    [str[0..3], str[4..9]],
    [str[0..5], str[6..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..5], str[6..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..6], str[7..9]],
    [str[0..3], str[4..6], str[7..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..9]],
    [str[0..6], str[7..9]]
  ]
end
```

Is there any way to improve the performance of the above method?

Comment: My money is on "no". I'm curious: why do you want to do that and why do you need better performance? I'd think your code would split 100,000 strings in the blink of an eye.

Comment: You'll end up with a lot of substring creation and copying. You might want to try this on an implementation like Rubinius, which AFAIK uses *ropes* instead of *strings* to implement the `String` class. The operations you are performing, are what ropes are very good at.

Comment: do you need to return an array always or just a string output as you've shown in your sample output?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was just curious whether there is a better way to do this

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes, I need to return array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could gain a bit of speed storing repetitive slices in variables:

```
def breakdown(str)
  s_0_2 = str[0..2]
  s_0_3 = str[0..3]
  s_6_9 = str[6..9]
  s_7_9 = str[7..9]
  [
    [str],
    [str[0..4], str[5..9]],
    [s_0_3, str[4..9]],
    [str[0..5], s_6_9],
    [s_0_2, str[3..5], s_6_9],
    [s_0_2, str[3..6], s_7_9],
    [s_0_3, str[4..6], s_7_9],
    [s_0_2, str[3..9]],
    [str[0..6], s_7_9]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  My benchmark test shows about 25% faster .

Answer (score 2):

What is your definition of "fast" ?  Did you bench mark it?

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'SecureRandom'

arr = []

100_000.times { arr << SecureRandom.hex(5)}

def breakdown(str)
  [
    [str],
    [str[0..4], str[5..9]],
    [str[0..3], str[4..9]],
    [str[0..5], str[6..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..5], str[6..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..6], str[7..9]],
    [str[0..3], str[4..6], str[7..9]],
    [str[0..2], str[3..9]],
    [str[0..6], str[7..9]]
  ]
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { arr.each{|a| breakdown a} }
end

       user     system      total        real
a  0.337387   0.001583   0.338970 (  0.341292)
```